# Comparison of Math::BigInt with scalars in Perl

Tags: perl

In following code there is comparison being made between BigInt object and perl scalar. Though it gives correct output, wanted to know
a) if it's fine to mix both. 
b) does the scalar gets promoted to BigInt

```
use Math::BigInt;
my $a = 11;
my $bInt = Math::BigInt->new("0xa");
print "a = $a";
print "bInt = $bInt\n";

if ($bInt < $a) {
    print "LESS\n";
} else {
    print "EQUAL OR GREATER\n";
}

Output:
a = 11
bInt = 10
LESS
```

Comment: Please avoid using `$a` and `$b`; these are used by `sort` and others, and declaring them as lexical variables could negatively affect calls you later add to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Math::BigInt objects overload comparison operators which means that any time they are used in a comparison, the overload will handle it properly, and it won't change the native value. There's some more details here: https://perldoc.pl/Math::BigInt#Mixing-different-object-types and of course, the [overload](https://perldoc.pl/overload) docs go into great detail.

Comment: Re "*Math::BigInt objects overload comparison operators*", Meaning that `$bInt < $a` is equivalent to `$bInt->blt($a)`.